# Android: Is there any api for Nimbuzz?

Tags: android, nimbuzz

I want to create an app something like as Nimbuzz... So I am searching for some use full api of Nimbuzz or something else equally to Nimbuzz

Comment: Nimbuzz is an app that contains (free chat, call etc.) http://www.nimbuzz.com

Comment: Bother searching before posting here? http://developers.nimbuzz.com/

Comment: @Arina : oh, asking about  Nimbuzz Chat  Messenger ,you can see http://blog.nimbuzz.com/2012/05/09/nimbuzz-opens-its-messenger-api-and-introduces-chat-buddy-developers-program/

Comment: Hey @ρяσѕρєя K thanks for suggestion. its good.. thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nimbuzz uses [xmpp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP). Explore [xmpp](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/). There are a lot of open source apps.
http://code.google.com/p/miranda/